# When element is animated with fadeIn/fadeOut, elements on top of it flicker

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

Demo here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7phyrsg/1/), once the page loads transition will file after 3 seconds.

Buttons in the top-left corner are flickering as images fade in/out. It is not specific to buttons, can be divs or other elements instead of buttons. It also is not specific to Bootstrap, if you remove Bootstrap CSS same thing happens.

Is this flickering velocity.js specific or is it a general issue with CSS animations? Couldn't find anything usable after about an hour spent searching the interwebs.

How could this be fixed?

N.B.
Got warning while writing this text that JSFiddle links have to be accompanied by code, so here is the sample code:

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn btn-warning">one</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">two</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <!-- CC BY: Timelapse Lezard by Deevad -->
  <img class="first" src="http://pre02.deviantart.net/6eb5/th/pre/f/2011/237/d/2/timelapse_lezard_by_deevad-d47rwef.png">
  <!-- CC BY: The Achkinnal Falls by FerdinandLadera -->
  <img class="second" src="http://img09.deviantart.net/a98b/i/2012/272/d/4/the_achkinnal_falls_by_ferdinandladera-d5gatw1.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.buttons
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.second').hide()

const showNextImage = function()
{
    $('.first')
    .velocity( 'fadeOut',
    {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function()
        {
            $('.second')
            .velocity( 'fadeIn',
            {
                duration: 500
            })
        },
    })
}

setTimeout( showNextImage, 3000 )


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/q7phyrsg/2/

You need `z-index: 999` on your buttons because the images are laid on top of them.

Comment: The issue was that image divs come after the buttons in HTML, so images are laid on top of the buttons. One way to fix flickering is to move buttons div after the images div and the other, if you can't move your divs around, is to set z-index on buttons high enough to pull their div above the images.
Thanks Cooper!